# Serial Data from Arduino to Python, Save Data tp File and Process Data

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

just getting into programming really but appreciate how powerful python is for collecting and post processing data. So I just trying to push myself over the hump.

I am just drip feeding data through the serial port using this code, to avoid any buffer issues;

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);

}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  int data = 0;
  while (data<50){
    data++;
    Serial.println(data);
    delay(1000);
   }
}
```

Then I want to read this data in python and save the data to a txt file as it comes in and do some simple averaging (just to push my understanding) using this script;

```
import serial 
import time 

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', baudrate= 9600, timeout = 1)
time.sleep(3)
numPoints = 50
dataList = [0]*numPoints
dataFile = open('SerialDataTest.txt', 'w')
numRowsCollect = 50

def getValues():

    ser.write(b'g')
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode().split('\r\n')  
    return arduinoData[0]

def printToFile(arduinoData,index):

    with open('SerialDataTest.txt', 'w') as dataFile:

        dataFile.write(arduinoData)


def getAverage(dataSet,row):

    dataAvg = sum(dataSet)/len(dataSet)
    print('Average for ' + str(row) + ' is: ' +str(dataAvg))

while(1):

    for row in range(0,numRowsCollect):
        for i in range(0,numPoints):
            data = getValues()
            printToFile(data,i)
            dataInt = int(data)
            dataList[i] = dataInt

            getAverage(dataList,row)

    dataFile.close()
    break
```

However the data does not seem to be saving at all and I bit confused why, I have tried my best to use the correct operations based on what I have read but the script returns;

```
Average for 0 is: 0
Average for 0 is: 0
Average for 0 is: 0
etc..
```

and my text file is blank :/ Any guidance from your experience would be really appreciated.

Thanks very much for your time

Comment: Firstly the function PrintToFile does not need to open the file again. Get rid of the whole ‘with’ line in that function.

Comment: Secondly the ‘while(1):’ line is redundant. Get rid of that, the extra indentation and the ‘break’.

Comment: Thirdly, I’m confused about rows. It looks like your Arduino only sends 50 values and then stops. Maybe the call to getAverage() is indented too much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I will review these points and let you know how it goes.